# Extruding is making a hollow object

Tags: extrude

After making an object, I wanted to extrude it and I got this hole in it
[image]

Comment: Can you reproduce it on a new plane?

Comment: Yes, I can do it again.

Comment: If nobody here, try to post screencast of your workflow. I can't reproduce it even with different select modes, extrude types, twisted normals or possible duplicated vertices.